# Broken or misconfigured gammu-smsd on Kali

Tags: kali-linux

I keep getting these errors:

```
Errors were encountered while processing: gammu-smsd
  E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

  gammu-smsd.service: 
    Unit configuration has fatal error, unit will not be started ~/systemd[1]: 
    /lib/systemd/system/gammu-smsd.service:9:
      Neither a valid executable name nor an absolute path:
      ${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_BINDIR}/gammu-smsd
```

Comment: gammu-smsd.service: Unit configuration has fatal error, unit will not be started      ~/systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/gammu-smsd.service:9: Neither a valid executable name nor an absolute path: ${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_BINDIR}/gammu-smsd

Answer (score 0):

The error message that did appear was the following:

```
maj 11 01:30:45 htpc.home.local systemd[1]: gammu-smsd.service: Unit configuration has fatal error, unit will not be started.
maj 11 01:30:45 htpc.home.local systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/gammu-smsd.service:9: Neither a valid executable name nor an absolute path: ${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_BINDIR}/gammu-smsd
maj 11 01:30:45 htpc.home.local systemd[1]: gammu-smsd.service: Unit configuration has fatal error, unit will not be started.
```

In order to resolve the above error I had to do the following steps:

```
cp /lib/systemd/system/gammu-smsd.service /etc/systemd/system/

// Edit line number 9

vim /etc/systemd/system/gammu-smsd.service +9
```

Enter the absolute path in within that file in my case:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gammu-smsd --pid=/var/run/gammu-smsd.pid --daemon
```

So remove the following it looks something like:

```
${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_BINDIR}/gammu-smsd
```

And replace that with the absolute path.